# Displaying Image in Devexpress DataGrid not working

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview, devexpress

I'm adding a new column to the Gridview using the following code

```
   GridColumn attachcolumn = new GridColumn() {

    Name = "TEST",
    FieldName = "TEST",
    UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Object,
    Caption = "TEST",
    //  ImageIndex = 0,
    ImageAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    ColumnEdit = new RepositoryItemPictureEdit(),
    //   ShowButtonMode = ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowOnlyInEditor
  };

  _gvSearchRes.Columns.Add(attachcolumn);
```

I'm setting the image like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= (_iDataRowCount - 1); i++)
  {
  _rgv.SetRowCellValue(i, "TEST", new Bitmap(10,10));
  }
```

The result i get is this.. The images are not displayed..Please advice 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are not displayed, because you are using an Unbound Column, but don't store your images anywhere. GridView doesn't save cell values itself. So, when you call the SetRowCellValue method, your images get lost. You need to store your unbound column values manually. To do this, handle the [CustomUnboundColumnData](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData) event and save your images, for example, in a dictionary. Please refer to [this example](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData#example-2) for a possible implementation.

Note that if you just need to show checkboxes, you don't need an unbound column. You can use [RepositoryItemCheckEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit.CheckBoxOptions) for this task. Set its [ValueChecked](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit.ValueChecked.property) property to "Yes" and [ValueUnchecked](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit.ValueUnchecked.property) property to "No". Then, assign this Repository Item to your column. As a result, you will see corresponding checkmarks in your column. If you wish, you can change the default image using the CheckBoxOptions property.

Comment: The thing im trying to achive is the following ---> Currently the Gridview contains a column with string elements.eg: if it contains "Yes" i need to display a tick mark,if it contains "No",then i need to display a wrong mark.What is the easiest way to substitute the string with image? Please advice..

Comment: In this case, you don't need an unbound column. You can use RepositoryItemCheckEdit for this task. Set its ValueChecked property to "Yes" and ValueUnchecked property to "No". Then, assign this Repository Item to your column. As a result, you will see corresponding checkmarks in your column. If you wish, you can change the default image using the CheckBoxOptions property.

Comment: Thanks... How do i set the Type of the GridView Column ? And can the checkbox image be altered programatically?